# Why is the Heterogeneous Lookup Comparator not the default?

Tags: c++, c++14

We have got heterogeneous lookup in C++14. I wonder why was the default comparator for map, set etc. not changed to less<>. Without this change average C++ user misses this feature completely and the performance penalty when looking for const char* in set<string> is still there. I have seen this pattern too many times in my company's codebase. Even MS showed this was a real perf bottleneck in one of its GoingNative videos. I can suspect the breaking of code was the issue but I don't see how it could happen for code which already worked in c++98/11

Answer (score 14):

Consider:

```
struct Foo { bool operator<(const Foo&) const;};
struct Bar { operator Foo() const; };

std::set<Foo> s;
Bar b;
s.find(b);
```

By default, `s` uses `std::less<Foo>`, and `s.find()` takes a `const Foo &`, so the lookup constructs one temporary `Foo` from the `Bar` and uses it for all comparisons.

In contrast, if `s` were changed to the transparent comparison functor `std::less<>`, then in combination with heterogeneous lookup each comparison in `find()` will be between a `Foo` and a `Bar`, so each comparison will construct a temporary `Foo`. This is a silent performance degradation.